# How to put Shift+v in a function?

Tags: vimscript

I'm trying to apply the `Shift-v` keymap in a vimscript, but not sure how.
I tried using `<s-v>` and `Shift-v` without success.

Comment: Isn't that just a capital V? `nnoremap V :echo "Hello World!"<CR>`

Comment: tried using `V` in a function but it didn't do anything...offtopic but trying something like `normal! gv` does work though.

Comment: Question is somewhat unclear though... What does the "in a function" part mean? How does that relate to mappings?

Comment: my bad, didn't meant to use the key-binding tag (it has no relation to keymapping, which the question illustrate better)

Comment: How about `normal! V` to start visual line selection? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yep! that works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> simply produces an uppercase V, so that's what you typically pass to Vim.

Whether it is to create a mapping for that keystroke:

```
:nnoremap V :echo "Hello World!"<CR>
```

Or to use `:normal!` to simulate that keystroke to start a visual line selection:

```
:normal! V
```

The `<S-` prefix does exist, but it's generally only used with special non-alphanumeric keys. For example, `<S-Tab>`, `<S-Left>` or `<S-F1>` (and note that Vim is not always able to recognize all these special keystrokes, it often depends on which terminal it's running on.)